# How do you create shadows in CSS for a DIV?

Tags: css

How to create shadows in css inside an element ?

I already tried this way but couldn't get anything:

`#element { shadow: 10px black; }`

Comment: google your title ... a little effort please ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this way:

```
.shadow {
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.shadow-inset {
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) inset;
}
```